# Uploading to dailymotion via proxy (php sdk)

Tags: php, curl, proxy, dailymotion-api

I want to upload via proxy but after setting the proxy value and connecting I get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DailymotionApiException' with message 'Invalid API server response'

Uploading only works without proxy and I've found absolutely no info on this subject.

```
$api = new Dailymotion();
$proxy = $api->proxy = "159.89.100.181:1999";
$timeoutx = $api->timeout = 9000; //set higher for slow proxies.
$depdi = $api->debug = false;
$comnn = $api->connectionTimeout = 9000;
$api->setGrantType(Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, $apikey, $apisecret, array('write','delete'), array('username' => $user, 'password' => $password)); 
$url = $api->uploadFile($videofile); 
$result = $api->call('video.create', array('url' => $url, 'title' => $videotitle , 'channel' => $videocategory , 'tags' => $videotags, 'description' => $videodescription, 'published' => true)); 
$videourl = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/'.$result['id'];
```

I have tested this with many proxies and always get the same error after connecting to the API successfully. Can anyone please tell me if uploading using proxy works for them?

Comment: are you sure the proxy is up and running. ( ie. can you ping it an whatnot )..  That's the obvious question.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes, I have tested with a lot of different ones, http, https, high anonymity, US, FR etc. They are all throwing the same error and it's starting to seem impossible to do. I'm certain it's not the proxy.

Comment: No I mean can you contact the proxy outside of the API, such as this way https://superuser.com/questions/621870/test-if-a-port-on-a-remote-system-is-reachable-without-telnet

Comment: See if the proxy is un-reahable the API will never work. so you can rule a lot of that out by testing the port on the proxy outside of the API.  It's been a wile since I had to do that myself, I got a guy for that at work now.  Mike, he does all that stuff or me now... lol  He is the `CTO` and I am the `CIO`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yea that might be the cause. Although if it gives the error Uncaught exception 'DailymotionApiException' with message 'Invalid API server response' it would seem to be connected to the API successfully but returning empty response. I'll test this on some different servers I guess. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's maybe due to a client_max_body_size exceeded in the proxy. Try to upload a very light video ( < 2Mb ex: [this video](http://www.rapconverter.com/sample-mp4-videos)) to check